# Vim: Can't set 'path' correctly to make 'gf' work

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get `gf` working with paths that look like this:

```
foo/bar.js
```

The file is located here: `/Users/dimal/dev/project/src/foo/bar.js`

So I set my `path` like this:

```
set path+=/Users/dimal/dev/project/src
```

It seems like `gf` should find the file but it doesn't.

```
E447: Can't find file "foo/bar.js" in path
```

Why?

I've tried other variations:

```
/Users/dimal/dev/project/src/**
/Users/dimal/dev/project/src/**/*
```

Comment: Give /**3 at the end. It means that, from src It will go three subdirectories deep and search. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. Just to clarify, the path should be this? `/Users/dimal/dev/project/src/**/3`

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong path there. I'm actually using this: `/Users/dimal/dev/project/src/**3`

Comment: Hi @SibiCoder. Thanks for you help. I commented above. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hey @SibiCoder. So, I tried closing MacVim and setting the path again, and for some reason it worked that time. If you put your comment answer into an **answer** answer, I can mark it as the correct solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gf commands searches for files in the paths include via `:set path`.

`set path` command accepts wildcards like `*`. (* means any character) So, if you wanted to include all files under subdirectories of a directory, you can give

```
      :set path+=directory/**
```

For a depth of three levels under a directory,  that is , to include files under any subdirectory of subdirectory of subdirectory of current directory, you can specify like `directory/**3`

Maximum depth allowed is 100.

A command like

```
       :set path+=/Users/dimal/dev/project/src/**3
```

will allow you to search for file named bar.js in `src/subdirectory/subdirectory/subdirectory` as well, not just in `src/`.